# License cost of IBM products on docker containers

Tags: ibm-mq

The license cost of IBM's websphere MQ is based on the number and type of the core of the CPU. For e.g. a CPU type would be called 70 PVU. Another core of a different CPU type may be 100 PVU. IBM states a price per PVU. Depending on the PVUs on the machine, the cost is decided.

If I have a physical machine with 4 cores and I install WMQ on it, I am charged X. If I create 10 docker containers on the same physical machine and allow each to utilize all 4 cores, will I be charged X or will I be charged 10X?

Regards,
Yash

Comment: The purpose of StackOverflow is to answer coding questions.  I believe billing questions should probably be directed towards your sales rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Happy to confirm that the answer to your query is that you would be charged X - not any multiple of it. The capacity pricing is licensing you for the capacity of the machine and it is then up to you as to how you make the most of that capacity - you can have 1, 5, 10 or more containers, or VMs or anything - and no other MQ licensing is required as you have licensed that machine capacity.